# Why can I draw a rectangle in pgfplots, but not a circle?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

```
\documentclass[11pt]{exam}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
xlabel=$x$, ylabel=$y$,
xmax =3, xmin =-3, ymax=3, ymin=-3,
axis lines = center,
xtick={-3,-2,...,3}, ytick={-3,-2,...,3},
axis line style={<->},
axis equal image,
]
\draw [red, thick,rounded corners] (axis cs:-1,-1) rectangle (axis cs:1,1);
\draw (axis cs:0,0) circle [blue, radius=1];
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{center}
\end{document}
```

This yields this:
[image: red rectangle and "blue circle"]

However, I would also like a circle to be included.

Comment: I have not my PC at hand now... Try to add a measurement unit to the radius of the circle. Also, a compat option could help.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. You can simply add `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.6}` to your preamble and you will get the desired result.

Comment: And the color `blue` should be moved to the `\draw` command.

Comment: Thank you, adding "\pgfplotsset{compat=1.6}" to the pre-amble fixed the problem. If I may, what does this line in the pre-amble do exactly?

Comment: @ZackaryCW, it means compatibility to version of `pgfplots`. The recent is 1.14 and I strongly encourage to upgrade your `pgfplots` installation to it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Everything was stated in the comments below the question already. Here again combined in an answer.

To answer your question in the comment, here a quote from the [PGFPlots manual section 2.2.1 on page 9 (v1.14)](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/contrib/pgfplots/doc/pgfplots.pdf#page=9).

> pgfplots 1.5.1 interpretes circle and ellipse radii as pgfplots
>   coordinates (older versions used pgf unit vectors which have no direct
>   relation to pgfplots). In other words: starting with version 1.5.1, it
>   is possible to write `\draw circle[radius=5]` inside of an axis. This
>   requires `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.5.1}` or higher.

So I have to revise my comment from above. It is sufficient to use a bit lower `compat` level. For the details please have a look at the comments in the code.

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    % -------------------------------------------------------------------------
    % this solves your problem
    % -------------------------------------------------------------------------
    % use this `compat' level or higher to use the improved features for
    % drawing circles/ellipses
    \pgfplotsset{compat=1.5.1}
    % -------------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            xlabel=$x$,
            ylabel=$y$,
            xmax=3,
            xmin=-3,
            ymax=3,
            ymin=-3,
            % it is simpler to use these commands than providing `xtick' and `ytick'
            xtick distance=1,
            ytick distance=1,
            axis lines=center,
            axis line style={<->},
            axis equal image,
        ]
            \draw [red, thick,rounded corners]
                (axis cs:-1,-1) rectangle (axis cs:1,1);
            % moved color option to the option block of the `\draw' command
            \draw [blue]
                (axis cs:0,0) circle [radius=1];
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]

Comment: Thanks for the answers! It really helped out, I re-read some of the pgfplots manual and you're right. Also, thanks for the xtick and ytick tip, writing this exam will be that much easier!

Comment: You are welcome. If it solved your problem please consider [accepting it](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852) (by clicking on the checkmark ✓).

Comment: Notice that `compat=1.11` or more will let you omit the `axis cs:` specifier, given that from that version onward axis coordinates system is the default. Highly recommended!

Comment: @Rmano, that is true and I know it, but I wanted to make clear what is the *root cause* why OP didn't get the circle he was expecting. I personally always use `compat=newest` (which currently equals to `compat=1.14`) to benefit from all the improved features.

Comment: @Stefan --- really the notice was for the OP ;-). Anyway, I think that `compat=newest` is bad, and basically defeat the idea of the `compat` flag... if you use `compat=1.14`, your source will compile in an identical way in the future... even if say, 1.18 will introduce some backward incompatible change.

Comment: @Rmano, that is true. But because I know that, if my created plot shall change in future, I could "simply" decrease `compat` level until it shows up as it should be or adapt the source code of the plot accordingly. (If I shouldn't already know knowing the `compat` level where the output changed I could look at the change log to find out *what* was changed to know *why* the output differs now.) (As always: Some stuff is just a matter of taste how to do it ...)