# How can one draw a simple circle with radius x on a pgfplots graph using tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I am having trouble drawing a simple circle on a graph using tikz. When I try cases from the documentation or other examples from different questions, I get a diagonal ellipse. Here's what I have so far.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{extarticle}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.8]
  \begin{axis}[
    axis y line=center,
    axis x line=middle, 
    axis on top=false,
    xmin=-6.5, xmax=6.5,
    ymin=-6.5, ymax=6.5,
    grid, 
    xtick={-6,...,6},
    xticklabels={-6,...,6},
    ytick={-6,...,6},
    yticklabels={-6,...,6},
    ]
     
    \draw (0,0) circle [radius=3];
    
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I end up with a diagonal ellipse when I use radius like so:
[image]

Then I tried using the ellipse format where I changed `\draw (0,0) circle [radius=3];` to `\draw (0,0) circle (45pt and 45pt);` As you can see from my result,
[image]
I get a circle, but it only seems to line up on the x-axis, and it overshoots the y-axis. Is the graph not actually square, or is it the formatting for the circle that's creating problems?

Comment: See e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/353535

Comment: Sorry, on second glance that question doesn’t seem to help.

Comment: Yeah, I just ran the code and I got the same ellipse or just the red square.

Comment: I guess it's because the draw-command is inside the axis-environment. Try to move it outside or addplot a circle within.

Comment: Add     "axis equal image"  inside the option of the axis enviromento in order to get same axis length.

Comment: Adding "axis equal image" was very helpful. It allowed me to keep a circle drawn inside the axis which also respects the coordinate system. When I put it outside of the axis, it doesn't respect the coordinates, even if I used ```(axis cs: 3,2)```. Is there a better way to find the radius than using points, or should I ask that as another question?

Comment: Just tested your code, and I get the expected result (https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nkx2o.png). Don't know why you get something else, can you show the `.log` file?

Comment: It seems to work for me as well now that I've added "axis equal image" to the code. I have an additional question about the radius, but I'll ask that in another question. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Also for me your code works perfectly fine -- as it should. The only thing I can think of what leads to this result is that you might have an outdated version of `tikz`. So could you show your LOG file or at least state your tikz version, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would seem that keeping the `\draw (x,y) circle[radius=?]` worked just fine after adding `axis equal image` to my code. My final working version is:

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.8]
  \begin{axis}[
    axis y line=center,
    axis x line=middle, 
    axis on top=false,
    axis equal image,
    xmin=-6.5, xmax=6.5,
    ymin=-6.5, ymax=6.5,
    grid, 
    xtick={-6,...,6},
    xticklabels={-6,...,6},
    ytick={-6,...,6},
    yticklabels={-6,...,6},
    ]   

    \draw (1,3) circle[radius=37pt];
  \end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

By keeping the draw inside the axis, I didn't have any additional problems with positioning the circle.